# Вывод переменной в цикле

Tags: java

Почему переменная `su` не выводится? Код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char z;
    String su;
    String data = "x";
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\txt.txt");

    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {

        int content;
        while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
            // Конвертируем в char
            z = (char)content;
            su = String.valueOf(z);
            if(su==data){
                System.out.println(su);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Строки сравниваются не через `==`, а через `equals()`: `string1.equals(string2)`.

Comment: Если `data` всегда будет из одного символа, то можно её сделать `char` и сравнивать прямо `char`-ы: `if (z == data)`